# TYPO3: Deferent wrap for RECORDS ifEmpty

Tags: typo3, typoscript

With the following Typoscript I get the value of `my_title` and if the field is empty the value of the field `title`:

```
lib.newsBreadcrumb = RECORDS
lib.newsBreadcrumb {
    dontCheckPid = 1
    tables = tx_news_domain_model_news
    source.data = GP:tx_news_pi1|news
    source.intval = 1
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news = TEXT
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.field = my_title
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.stdWrap.ifEmpty.field = title
    conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.htmlSpecialChars = 1
    wrap = <li>|</li>
}
```

Now I would like to use a diferent wrap for the value of the field `my_title`.

Desired result:

```
<li><bold>my_title</bold></li>
```

versus

```
<li>title</li>
```

What I can do, is setting a different wrap for the `ifEmpty` part, but I don't get it to work for the "default" part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify the fallback ([TSref: stdWrap.field](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#field)):

```
conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.field = my_title // title
```

The *wrap*-property of TEXT has *stdWrap*-properties. So, you have the *[override](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#override)*-property (which has also *stdWrap*-properties):

```
conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.wrap = <li>|<li>
conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.wrap.override = <li><bold>|</bold><li>
conf.tx_news_domain_model_news.wrap.override.if.isTrue.field = my_title
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Unfortunately this is not working, I get always the wrap of the `override` part regardles whether it is empty or not.

Comment: Ah, sorry. `ifEmpty` does a bit different. We need `if.isTrue.field` instead. 
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/Stdwrap.html#ifempty https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/master/en-us/Functions/If.html#istrue

Comment: Wow nice, that is working! Maybe you adjust your answer and I will accept it later? Thanks a lot!